# XCode cannot find foundation.h or UIKit.h after MediaPlayer.framework is added

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, media-player, ios-frameworks

As soon as I add the MediaPlayer.framework into a new program, XCode absolutely shits its pants. Under supporting Files, PROJECTNAME-Prefix.phc starts red-flagging both #import  and #import

Why is it doing this? I have tried to create a new project and re-adding the Framework, but even if that is all I have done, it gives 4 errors on the first failed build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using xcode4 don't slide the framework in the project: it edit the framework search path and do the error you describe.
 Try deleting the framework search path in project "build setting" and for adding the framework use "target" "build phase" "link binary with library".

hope it help and sorry for my poor english.